# Sum Of Time In RDLC Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I want to sum this **WorkedHours** in RDLC Report..WorkedHours type is Varchar..

```
WorkedHours
  04:00:25
  07:23:01
  11:02:15
```

like Total: 22:25:41

How Can I Achieve It ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TimeStamp class gether with the Sum function,
follow an example:

> =TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Sum(Fields!Dirigindo.Value))

Answer (score 0):

You need to either calculate it in the Dataset. Perhaps casting it to a proper date time format (you can give it a dummy date component such as 1900-01-01 and then perform the calculation use Datediff):

or use an SSRS expression using the TimeSpan object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx